# UtcNow.ToLocalTime() returns UTC time instead of local time on CentOS

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application where I need to convert UTC `DateTime`s to local server times. This software runs both on Linux (CentOS 7) and Windows.

On Windows, the code works as expected: `DateTime.UtcNow` returns UTC time and `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()` returns the time adjusted to current server time.

However, on CentOS, `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()` returns the same UTC time instead of local time:

```
$"Utc: {DateTime.UtcNow}, Kind: {DateTime.UtcNow.Kind}";
$"Local: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()}, Kind: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().Kind}";
```

Outputs

```
"Utc: 07/19/2018 10:53:03, Kind: Utc"
"Local: 07/19/2018 10:53:03, Kind: Local"
```

While the CentOS Server time should be UTC+3:

```
$ date
Thu Jul 19 13:55:14 EEST 2018
```

Edit: `DateTime.Now` also returns current time as UTC instead of the local time.

Comment: What does `echo $TZ` or `env | grep TZ` say? What does `readlink -f /etc/localtime` say? What does `file /etc/localtime` say?

Comment: `echo $TZ` and `env | grep TZ` print nothing, `readlink -f /etc/localtime` prints `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Helsinki` and `file /etc/localtime` prints `/etc/localtime: symbolic link to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Helsinki'`. Helsinki is the expected +3 timezone.

Comment: Does `DateTime.Now` produce the same result?

Comment: Also, what specific version of the .NET Core Runtime are you running?  Have you tried on the latest 2.1.2?  I would prefer not to hunt down bugs if they have been fixed already. ;)

Comment: `DateTime.Now` outputs the same time as `UtcNow`. I also tried with the latest `microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-runtime` docker image and the problem persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously I should have mentioned that I'm using Docker. This is apparently a Docker feature - containers don't share the host's timezones. I solved this by defining the timezone in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  ...:
    image: ...
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Helsinki"
```